# Equivalent of kwargs in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to create a Typescript class RepeatLoader whose job is to take a function, which loads some data and will be run in a while loop until a callback which checks whether some condition is true stops it.

This currently looks something like this:

```
class RepeatLoader() {
    loadDataFunc: () => void,
    shouldLoadCallback: () => boolean
    
    constructor(loadDataFunc, shouldLoadCallback) {
        this.loadDataFunc = loadDataFunc;
        this.shouldLoadCallback = shouldLoadCallback
    }
    
    startRunning() {
        while(this.shouldLoadCallback()) {
             this.loadDataFunc()
             sleep(3000)
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to pass dynamic parameters to the loadDataFunc.
Something like a loadDataParams object that either gets passed through the constructor or the startRunning function.

Coming from Python, this would be a textbook example for **kwargs.
But I'm not sure how to do this in Typescript. Does someone have suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html):

```
class RepeatLoader<A extends unknown[]> {
    loadDataFunc: (...args: A) => void
    shouldLoadCallback: () => boolean

    constructor(loadDataFunc: (...args: A) => void, shouldLoadCallback: () => boolean) {
        this.loadDataFunc = loadDataFunc
        this.shouldLoadCallback = shouldLoadCallback
    }

    startRunning(...args: A) {
        while (this.shouldLoadCallback()) {
            this.loadDataFunc(...args)
            sleep(3000)
        }
    }
}

// Usage:

const shouldLoadCallback = (): boolean => { /* ... */ }

const foo = new RepeatLoader(
  (x: number, y: number) => console.log(x + y),
  shouldLoadCallback
)
foo.startRunning(1, 2)

const bar = new RepeatLoader(
  ({x, y}: {x: number; y: number}) => console.log(x + y),
  shouldLoadCallback
)
bar.startRunning({x: 1, y: 2})
```

- The `A extends unknown[]` means that `A` needs to be some kind of array, which allows us to do `(...args: A)`
- The `(...args: A)` is like Python’s `*args`
- The closest thing you can get to Python’s `**kwargs` is by doing something like `bar` in the example above: using a single object parameter

If you only want `loadDataFunc` to take one parameter, you can do this:

```
class RepeatLoader<T> {
    loadDataFunc: (arg: T) => void
    shouldLoadCallback: () => boolean

    constructor(loadDataFunc: (arg: T) => void, shouldLoadCallback: () => boolean) {
        this.loadDataFunc = loadDataFunc
        this.shouldLoadCallback = shouldLoadCallback
    }

    startRunning(arg: T) {
        while (this.shouldLoadCallback()) {
            this.loadDataFunc(arg)
            sleep(3000)
        }
    }
}
```

but the first way is more general.

Comment: Nice, good idea thanks. While I find the first solution more elegant I will probably stick with the second, since it seems slightly easier, and reflects the idea of having a params object more. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: And unfortunately I can't upvote your comment since i don't have enough reputation, but I marked it as the correct anwer.